# Device that makes metal malleable

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember reading a story about an alien who came to earth and gave/sold a human a little device.  It was the size of a pen, and when you aimed it at something metal, the metal became malleable, like clay.  A second time, and the metal resolidified.  When the alien came back not long after, human civilization had completely fallen to pieces because of it.  Does anyone know the name and author of the story?

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE. Can you remember any other details, like when you read it and when you think it was written? Any additional details at all are helpful.

Comment: I was thinking that I knew this one, but I believe it was actually a bit of spy/action fiction where it was simply played straight as a nifty device.

Comment: I believe I read it for the first time in 1975.

Comment: I found it.  It's "Technological Retreat", by C.G. Edmondson.

Comment: As a side note, for other drawn in by the title, there are such devices in various Larry Niven stories that involve protectors. Particularly in the *Ringworld* sequels and the *<Noun> of Worlds* series.

Comment: Isn't it kind of tacky to get credit for answering my own question?

Comment: @Lisa Not at all! [It's encouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking). There's even [a badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/13/self-learner) for it, if you care about that sort of thing

Answer (score 11):

Turns out it's "Technological Retreat", by C.G. Edmondson.  It's not surprising that it was so hard to find, since it's only appeared in one book.

https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?74265