# Metal-softening tool

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A pair of alien "door-to-door salesmen" comes down to Earth and meets a citizen. They show him some interesting but unsuitable wares, and then a small, cylindrical device that softens any metal that it is applied to, to the point where a person could manipulate steel like putty. The metal can be hardened again after the desired shape is attained. Very useful for hobby sculpture, the traders say. The Earthman "drives a hard bargain" -- in reality, both sides are satisfied -- for a promised delivery of, say, ten thousand of these devices.

But it turns out that the device isn't hard to duplicate, and soon anyone who wants one can have one. Pranksters are a problem, and as railways are softened and a suspension bridge is left sagging, more than just an irritant. By the time the traders return, many years later (the deal didn't include a due date), terrestrial civilization has collapsed and tribesmen threaten them with stone-tipped spears. They look at each other and one says, more or less, "What are we going to do with a cargo of ten thousand metal softeners?"

I read this English-language story probably in an anthology during the 1960s, or at latest the 70s.

Comment: I'm closing this as duplicate of the older question, since the asker answered it themselves, and accepted it in a comment.  Sadly they didn't mark it as accepted though.

Comment: @OrganicMarble the newest question is more detailed, though. Maybe that should be closed the other way? DavidW provided a link to the story, there's way to improve b_jonas' answer and make this thread a better dupe-target, I think

Comment: Yeah, but the newest answer has no detail.  If you want to fix it up, I think I can reverse the closure, although I've never tried.  There's no same in being dupe-closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like [a previous answer on our site by Lisa](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/89650/4918) matches your description.  The story is [G. C. Edmondson, “Technological Retreat” (1956)](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?74265).

Comment: Yes, thanks! I originally read it in _13 Great Stories of Science Fiction_, edited by Groff Conklin (1960).

Comment: If posible, flesh the answer out; the question is very nice and should be used as dupe-target rather than the other :)

Comment: The full text of the story is available [at the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v010n05_1956-05_PDF/page/n37) for anyone who feels ambitious enough to improve the answer.